# Traveling to US for only 4 days. What will happen with Biden's mandatory quarantine?

Tags: usa, covid-19, quarantine

I have a flight to the US (from Argentina) on Feb 14 arriving Feb 15, departing Feb 18.

I wanted to buy some things on President's day, and go to Universal on 16th, and Disney on 17th.

USA already requests negative PCR test before traveling.

So what now? What problems could I face if I stick to my plan?

Comment: Right now I don't think anyone can give an exact answer - the [executive order](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/presidential-actions/2021/01/21/executive-order-promoting-covid-19-safety-in-domestic-and-international-travel/) says that they will aim to implement quarantine, and it will be in line with CDC guidelines, but it does not state what the exact rules will be. However, it's very difficult to imagine any kind of quarantine rule that allows a four-day trip with shopping and visiting tourist attractions...

Comment: I must be living on a different planet. On mine there’s a virus spreading all over which already killed 2 million people and the last thing you would want to do is travel everywhere for leisure and visit places where there could be lots of people...

Comment: Well, you wont be travelling the the US for just 4 days and still be doing all those things... Thats kinda the point.  To stop people like you potentially bringing the virus in just for non-essential travel reasons.  You want to travel for 4 days plus the mandatory quarantine at a minimum.

Comment: @Moo USA already requires negative PCR, plus I travel for monetary reasons and planned to do some things in the mean time

Comment: @JorgeeFG you are going to Universal and Disney - unless you are going to a practical job interview or to buy the parks themselves, its non-essential travel.  Non-PCR test only means you tested negative at that exact moment the test was taken, not a moment afterward - its like relying on a negative pregnancy test as birth control.

Comment: The US should be able to eliminate lockdowns by summer when all vulnerable people are vaccinated. I'd postpone my trip to September to avoid the uncertainty. Consider flying to Mexico instead which has no COVID travel rules right now.

Comment: As of right this moment, you should have no issues with your trip. It's doubtful that Biden has any more powers than Trump to stop Covid19 or any other virus. Are you going to California or Florida? You will have to comply with the state level regulations upon arrival, it's unlikely that you'll be able to do these things in California but should be fine in Florida.

Comment: To be fair to Op, one of the problems with continued travel at the moment is that if the flight is going ahead and the hotel he's staying at is open, he's probably not eligible to get his money back if he wants to cancel or delay the trip.

Comment: Are you going to Florida or California?  I'm unsure about Florida, but in California the Disneyland and Universal theme parks are both closed indefinitely

Comment: @JonathanReez ugh don't suggest people come to Mexico!  Despite having little to no COVID travel rules, much of Mexico is still on lockdown (started March 2020) and COVID is widespread here.  They're not restricting travel in, and some of the tourist areas are BUSY - it brings in a LOT of money - but many of the locals are out of work, food, home, because of the lockdowns, and these just won't stop while there's such an influx of tourists that can't go anywhere else

Comment: @Midavalo I believe that it's okay to travel anywhere as long as you follow all the local laws. If the country says tourism is banned, don't try to sneak in. If it's allowed, go ahead. Just make sure you don't bring in COVID to the country by being vigilant about mask wearing and social distancing.

Comment: @JonathanReez, it is one thing to bend the rules yourself, it is much worse to advise people to do so. There is a world wide 'do not travel unless essential' request. Do not point out loopholes, and advise people to stay home as much as possible till the situation improves a lot.

Comment: @Moo it's even worse than that: a negative test means you *probably* didn't have the reasons *a few days before the test was taken*. You could have already caught the virus and test negative during the incubation period. So all the rage about "having a test taken in the last 72 hours" is really just BS. It will eliminate a few positive cases, but by far not all of them (that is proven nearly every day in news stories about people who had a negative test but then were positive at the next test a few days later, e.g. the British in Vallorcine or many of the people going to the Australian open).

Comment: @JamesPD Did they make their plans a year ago? people should know by now that conditions may change.

Comment: @jcaron It's no BS, the mandatory tests are meant to serve as a deterrent. The hassle of having to get tested will by itself discourage quite a few people from planning non-essential trips. So does the risk of potentially losing money paid for flights and hotels should the test come out positive. Without a mandatory test, many people who feel "just a bit under the weather" will take a planned leisure trip because "otherwise the money would go to waste (which would be a real shame)".

Comment: @jcaron yes you do. On my planet no human being has a lifespan even near to the 3500 years

Comment: People choosing to travel recreationally during a pandemic to go to places like "Universal" and "Disney" is one reason why this pandemic continues to spread and people continue to die.  A friend of a friend did exactly this, and now his entire extended family (including a 96 year old man) is suffering from COVID-19, and who knows how many people they infected during their travels.  Traveling long distances is even a worse thing to do, because that's how new strains are spread.

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr version**

You can probably get away with what you are planning.  But if you choose to do so I will consider you to be the sort of person who does not care for the wellbeing of yourself or (more importantly) other people around you.

**Long version**

Biden's executive order can be found [here](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/presidential-actions/2021/01/21/executive-order-promoting-covid-19-safety-in-domestic-and-international-travel/)

In the case of the OP the relevant paragraph is probably:

> **Sec. 5.  International Travel.**
>
> ..
>
> (ii)  required to comply with other applicable CDC guidelines
> concerning international travel, including recommended periods of
> self-quarantine or self-isolation after entry into the United States.

The CDC recommendations can be found [here](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/after-travel-precautions.html).  The CDC only recommends quarantine:

> If you participated in higher-risk activities during your
> international travel

Which are listed as (my emphasis):

> - Travel from a country or U.S. territory with a Level 2, Level 3, or    Level 4 Travel Health Notice.
> - Going to a large social gathering like a wedding, funeral, or party.
> - Attending a mass gathering like a sporting event, concert, or parade.
> - Being in crowds like in restaurants, bars, fitness centers, or movie    theaters.
> - Taking public transportation like trains or buses or being in    **transportation hubs like airports**.
> - Traveling on a cruise ship or river boat.

But the site also says

> You may have been exposed to COVID-19 on your travels. You may feel
> well and not have any symptoms, but you can be contagious without
> symptoms and spread the virus to others. You and your travel
> companions (including children) pose a risk to your family, friends,
> and community for 14 days after you travel.

At this point I'll point out that a negative PCR test only shows you were negative (within the bounds of the accuracy of the test) **at the time you took the test**.  So there is scope for being infected *after* you have taken your test, and the *more* people you are around, the *higher* the chance of encountering someone who could infect you.

The CDC site also says

> Always follow state and local recommendations or requirements related
> to travel.

My [state](https://cv.nmhealth.org/travel-recommendations/) has mandatory 14 day quarantine for *any* out of state visitors.  And the penalty for breaking that quarantine can be:

> Non-compliant individuals are subject to involuntary quarantine by the
> New Mexico Department of Health under the Public Health Emergency
> Response Act.

So at the Federal and CDC level they talk about recommendations only. At the state level it becomes more strict and there can be actual penalties.

But no one that I know of is currently suggesting GPS monitoring (a la Cayman Islands) for the US. So adhering to the restrictions is up to you to follow. However last year at least some tourists in Hawaii were [arrested](https://www.sacbee.com/news/coronavirus/article247263119.html) for breaking local quarantine restrictions.

Comment: Minor comment: if OP already had COVID (not unlikely, based on the deaths count 20+% of Argentina already had COVID) or was already vaccinated, the equation changes and its likely safe to travel. Otherwise agreed - safer to stay home currently.

Comment: @JonathanReez There have been reports of people getting covid more than once.  And while I agree that getting vaccinated is the thing to do, none of the current guidelines even address that possibility - so that aspect is currently up in the air

Comment: Actually, a negative PCR test shows you were negative **a few days before the test**. During the incubation period, you already have the virus, but still test negative. So a positive test says you have the virus. A negative test does not mean anything at all.

Comment: @jcaron to be safe you should follow the NZ golden standard and self isolate for 14 days after which you do a COVID test. Then wear an N95 mask at all times around others, especially on the flight. Otherwise yes, the test is not a guarantee.